# Raphael repeat animation without delay

Tags: javascript, raphael

```
obj.animate(anim.repeat('Infinity').delay(500));
```

The cycle of repeating of this is in fact: Delay, animation, delay, animation, delay animation... and so on.

How to make it: delay, animation, animation, animation... and so on - delay is only in first cycle.

I don't want to use `setTimeout`, because I'm animating a lot of elements and each setTimeout has different instance of javascript browser timer and animation od different elements may be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

This is curious. I thought you could cleverly update it this way, using the optional callback parameter, but this does NOT work:

```
anim = Raphael.animation({transform: "r45"}, 500, function(e) {  anim.del = 0; }).delay(1000);
```

From glancing at the source, it looks like the parameters of the animation are not updated on each iteration (I think).

This works, though I don't know how functionally different it is from the setTimeout method:

```
var paper = Raphael(0,0,500,500),
    square = paper.rect(50,50,50,50).attr("fill", "#009900"),
    //anim = Raphael.animation({transform: "r45"}, 500, function(e) {  console.log(anim); anim.del = 0; }).delay(1000);
    anim = Raphael.animation({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() { this.attr("opacity", 1); /* this callback is just to reset the effect for my dummy animation */ }),
    wait = Raphael.animation({opacity: 1}, 500, function () { this.animate(anim.repeat("Infinity")); /* this callback triggers the actual animation after a 500ms placebo animation */ });

square.animate(wait);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktbWX/1/)

As you can see, this just runs a 500ms animation with no visual effect one time and then invokes the actual animation on callback.